# Каким образом можно скопировать все записи внутри таблицы с одним id на другой id учитывая все даты на sql

Tags: sql, postgresql9.5

В общем есть два расписания, они хранятся в одной таблице, у одного time_table_name_id равное 1 у другого 2, грубо говоря нужно сделать копию первого расписания, скопировав time и actionn во второе учитывая дату чтобы она совпадала в обоих расписаниях и так же чтобы совпадал параметр num_in_day.
Пока пришел только к этому запросу, но тут я изменяют только один день.

```
update file1
set time = (select time from file1
           where time_table_name_id=1 and day ='2023-01-01' and num_in_day = 0),
    actionn = (select actionn from file1
           where time_table_name_id=1 and day = '2023-01-01' and num_in_day = 0)
where time_table_name_id=2 and day = '2023-01-01' and num_in_day = 0;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так, чтобы это срабатывало для всех дат.

[image: структура таблицы]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрите пример с MERGE.
В вопросе нет необходимости добавления записей в расписание2, если они присутствуют в расписание1. Если необходимо, можно изменить секцию **WHEN NOT MATCHED**

```
merge into file1  a
using file1  b 
  on a.time_table_name_id=2 
  and b.day=a.day and b.num_in_day=a.num_in_day 
  and b.time_table_name_id=1
when matched then
  update 
  set action=b.action,time=b.time
when not matched and time_table_name_id=1 then
  insert (num_in_day  ,day ,time  ,action,time_table_name_id) 
  values(b.num_in_day,b.day,b.time,b.action,2) -- 2 - time_table_name_id
;
```

Предполагается, что поле **Id** описано как **Identity** (типа **id int generated by default as identity**), или что-то другое автоматически назначаемое.